# can't find the logs from log

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I am trying to find where it logs hi starting with `log()` function. I am new to flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  log("hi starting");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I try to look at `Logcat` or the terminal but those logs seem to be about the system processes. Here is an example pic:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run your code and then the message is shown in the Run section:
[image]